# Why $A^L$ is a split semi-simple $L$-algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, representation-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

[image]

[image]

My question in the line 5 of the proof of $(i)\Rightarrow (ii)$. I wonder why $A^L$ is a split semi-simple $L$-algebra...

Thank you very much!!

Comment: I think they are using the fact that if $A$ is split semisimple over some field $K$, then $A^M$ will be split semisimple over any extension field $M$ of $K$. So $A^L$ is split semisimple, because $A^E$ is and $A^L=(A^E)^L$.

Comment: Why $A^L$ is split semisimple, because $A^E$ is and $A^L=(A^E)^{L}$？

Comment: My question is just why $A^L$ is split semisimple?

Comment: Is that not because $M_n(K)\otimes_K M\simeq M_n(M)$ for all field extensions $M/K$? If $A^E\simeq\prod_{i=1}^tM_{n_i}(E)$, then $A^L\simeq\ldots$

Comment: Thank you! What really confused me is $M_n(K)\otimes_KM≃M_n(M)$, it may be Intuitively, but I failed to prove it.